# Pull specific control out of a silverlight listbox given a random index into the list?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

I have a listbox which uses the following template to bind a list of clips.  I would like to pull one of those clips at random and have it play.  That is the easy part and is pretty straight forward.  I would then like to make an associated image visible.  I can't seem to find out how to get the controls associated with the index in the listbox.  Any ideas.

`

```
            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,12" Width="420">
                <Button Click="Button_Click" Background="{StaticResource PhoneAccentBrush}" 
                        Height="90" Width="420" x:Name="btn">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" >
                        <Image x:Name="Selected" Width="75" Source="Images/Playing.png" Visibility="Collapsed" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" TextWrapping="NoWrap" Width="330" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextLargeStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </Button>
            </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a ListBox so have a list of objects bound to its ItemsSource.  Add a new "NowPlaying" property to the class of these objects.  Bind this property to the Visibility property of the "Selected" Image via a [BoolToValueConverter](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/05/28/a-generic-boolean-value-converter.aspx)

Now you just toggle that new property and need not delve in the Visual Tree to do what the binding system should be doing for you

Comment: Very nice!!  It worked beautifully.  I really need to get my head into this "new" thinking. :)

Answer (score 1):

To find the conrols that have been generated from your template you can use the methods on `ItemContainerGenerator`. For example, if you want to find the elements at index '5', do the following:

```
ListBoxItem lbi = listBox.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(5) as ListBoxItem;
```

There are various other methods that allows you to find the container given a bound model item for example.

You can then navigate the visual tree, (I wrote a helper called [Linq-to-VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/) that makes this a bit easier) to locate the elements you require. To find the image:

```
var image = lbi.Descendants<Image>().Single() as Image;
```